# react-query returns previous data

Tags: reactjs, react-query

#### Versions

```
react@17.0.2
react-query@3.34.15
```

#### Description

I have some problem with manual update cache.

code looks like

```js
/* filter for query */
const [companyName, setCompanyName] = useState('');
/* get users by companyName */
const { data } = useQuery(
  ['users', { companyName }],
  () => getUsers({ companyName })
);
/* update user by id */
const updateUser = useMutation(
  (userPatch) => updateUser(userPatch),
  {
    onSuccess: (_, variables) => {
      /* get cache for queries and call updater for each */
      queryClient.setQueriesData(['users'], (oldData) => {
        const newUsers = oldData.users.map((user) => {
          if (user.user_id !== newUserData.user_id) return user;

          return { ...user, ...variables };
        });

        return { ...oldData, users: newUsers };
      });
    },
  }
);
```

I see that cache for all queries updated (via `ReactQueryDevtools`) but `useQuery` return previous result.

#### Question

**What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: code looks good, but I wouldn't closure over `data` from useQuery, but use `queryClient.getQueryData()` to get the latest data, or use the functional updater from setQueriesData. Are you sure that the react-query devtools show the updated values? What I can imagine is that a browser focus event triggers a refetch, which might give you different data back?

Comment: you are right. I updated code but it does not help. I've updated code

Comment: Can you reproduce the behavior in a codesandbox?

Comment: @TkDodo I found problem. The problem was with object mutation in another place of code. My colleague used `Objects.assign` with data from `useQuery` as first argument.